# Kohana many-to-many relationship "has many - through"

Tags: php, orm, many-to-many, kohana, relationship

I'm using kohana v3.3, and i would like to know if there is a possibility to get/save another data in the pivot table or not ?

let's take the Auth example :

- So we have 3 tables (roles, users, roles_users) and i added another column **"date"** on the pivot table

**Tables :**

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
>
> `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>
> `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
>
> `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
>
> UNIQUE KEY `uniq_name` (`name`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_users` (
>
> `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>
> `role_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>
> **`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,**
>
> PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`role_id`),
>
> KEY `fk_role_id` (`role_id`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> --
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
>
> `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>
> `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
>
> `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>
> `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
>
> `logins` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>
> `last_login` int(10) UNSIGNED,
>
> PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
>
> UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`),
>
> UNIQUE KEY `uniq_email` (`email`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

**Models**

- *Model Role*

> class Model_Auth_Role extends ORM {
>
> protected $_has_many = array(
>
> ```
>   'users' => array('model' => 'User','through' => 'roles_users'),
> ```
>
> );

- *User Model*

> class Model_Auth_User extends ORM {
>
> protected $_has_many = array(
>
> ```
>   'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' =>
> ```
>
> 'roles_users'),
>
> );

**Controller**

> public function action_create()
>
> {
>
> ```
>   $model = ORM::factory('user');
>
>   $model->username = 'myusername';
>
>   $model->password = 'password';
>
>   $model->email = 'test@example.com';
>
>   $model->save();
>
>   **// How can i set the "date" to "roles_users" table ?**
>
>   $model->add('roles', ORM::factory('role')->where('name', '=',
> ```
>
> 'login')->find());
>
> }
>
> puboic function action_get()
>
> {
>
> $users = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
>
> ```
>   foreach ($users as $user)
>
>   {
>
>       $roles = $user->roles->find_all();
>
>       echo $user->email." : <br>";
>
>       **// How can i get the "date" from "roles_users" table ?**
>
>       foreach ($roles as $role)
>
>           echo " ->".$role->name."<br>";
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }

**Questions**

I have two questions :

1- How can i set the "date" to "roles_users" table ? on controller action_create()

2- How can i get the "date" from "roles_users" table ? on controller action_get()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you want, you can do two things:

- Create a seperate `Model_Roles_User` and use it to create the relationship and get/set its properties.

This would require you to add an `id AUTO_INCREMENT` column as Kohana does not natively support compound keys; or be a good man and extend kohana's functionality to support it :-)

- Leave it as is and use some custom queries to `SELECT` or `UPDATE` the rows

This should also be fairly easy:

```
$result = DB::select('date')
    ->from('roles_users')
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->and_where('role_id', '=', $role_id)
    ->execute();
```

The answer to question #1 is rather easy. The database already takes care of this! (`date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`)

Comment: You can thank me by voting my answer up and accept it if it fully answers your question.

Comment: (Sorry i forget to publish all the message)

- I prefer to avoid using many sql requests, is there another way to get/set data from/into Roler_Users table ? i tried to add `"$_belongs_to (roles,users) into Model_Roles_Users"` but no way.
i'm looking for something like `echo $user->roles->user_role->date`

- I'm agree, the database take care of the default insert, but if i want to put something else for example (Day-5), i would like to use something like 
`$user->roles->user_role->date = getTime($Day-5);
$user->save();
`

Comment: In that case `Create a seperate Model_Roles_User and use it to create the relationship and get/set its properties.`

Comment: can you please give me an example, i'm not an expert